# Create a class with getters based on the properties of another class

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have a class A with a hundred properties:

```js
class A {
  FOO = "foo";
  BAR = "bar";
  // (...) 98 more properties
}
```

In typescript, how does one go about dynamically defining a class B with one getter for each property of class A?
The corresponding statically defined class B would look like this:

```js
class B {
  get FOO() {
    someFunction('FOO');
  }

  get BAR() {
    someFunction('BAR');
  }

  // (...) 98 more getters
}
```

The relation between these classes is as follows:

- a getter name in B is equal to property name in A
- the body of getter in B is exactly the call of function `someFunction` with a single argument that is a string with the name of the getter

Comment: In what way do the two classes relate to each other?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I have added more information to the question. Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to define getters on the fly:

```js
class A {
    FOO = "foo";
    BAR = "bar";
    // (...) 98 more properties
}

function someFunction(p) {
    console.log('someFunction', p)
}

class B {
    constructor(a) {
        for (let p of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a))
            Object.defineProperty(this, p, {
                get: () => someFunction(p) 
            })
    }
}

b = new B(new A)
b.FOO
b.BAR
```

I guess you need to pass `a` to `someFunc` as well, otherwise how would it know from which object to pick the property?

Another is to use a `Proxy`:

```js
class A {
    FOO = "foo";
    BAR = "bar";
    // (...) 98 more properties
}

function someFunction(p) {
    console.log('someFunction', p)
}

class B {
    constructor() {
        return new Proxy({}, {
            get(target, p) {
                return p in target ? Reflect.get(target, p) : someFunction(p)
            }
        })
    }
}

b = new B()
b.FOO
b.BAR
```

In the latter case B and A are in fact independent, so that B is just a "hollow" object that redirects everything to `someFunc`.

Answer (score 1):

This is @georg answer, second suggestion, slightly changed to actually work for me:

```js
class A {
    FOO = "foo";
    BAR = "bar";
    // (...) 98 more properties
}

function someFunction(p, moreStuff) {
    console.log('someFunction', p, moreStuff)
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(private something: Something) {
        super();
        const someth = this.something;
        return new Proxy({} as any, {
            get(target, p) {
                return p in target ? Reflect.get(target, p) : someFunction(p, someth)
            }
        })
    }
}

b = new B()
b.FOO
b.BAR
```

Comment: What's the difference between this answer and the answer @georg gave?

Comment: The important difference is the fact that B extends from A and that the first argument to Proxy is `{} as any`. Without this I get an error when I try to access FOO from `b`: b.FOO.
Then there is the irrelevant difference (not relevant to the question because I forgot to mention it) that is the fact that the constructor has an argument `something` that is used lately in someFunction.